# proving $\frac{1}{n+3}+\frac{1}{n+4}+...+\frac{1}{2n+4}>\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, summation

how can one prove that:
$\frac{1}{n+3}+\frac{1}{n+4}+...+\frac{1}{2n+4}>\frac{1}{2}$

For all natural $n$, 
**without** using induction?

thank you.

Comment: One can use $AM\geq HM$ and get the lower bound, where $AM$ means arithmetic mean, $HM$ Harmonic mean.

Comment: why the down vote? if i knew who t solve it without induction, i would not ask

Comment: @bony The community expects you to show what effort you had put into solving the question before you posted it here.

Comment: oh i see, i thought that if i said /;without using induction" so it is obvious that i tried but succeeded only by that approach. thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{n+3}+\frac{1}{n+4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n+4}>\frac{1}{2n+4}+\frac{1}{2n+4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n+4}=(n+2)\cdot\frac{1}{2n+4}=\frac{1}{2}$$

as $\frac{1}{2n+4}$ is the least term in the sum, and there are $(n+2)$ terms.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, the sum

$$S_n = \sum_{k=n+3}^{2 n+4} \frac1{k} $$

decreases with $n$. Thus, let's rewrite

$$ S_n = H_{2 n+4} - H_{n+3} $$

where

$$H_m = \sum_{k=1}^m \frac1k $$

Note that $H_m = \log{m} + \gamma +O(1/m)$ as $m$ increases without bound.  Thus,

$$S_n = \log{(2 n+4)} + \gamma - \log{(n+3)} - \gamma + O\left (\frac1n \right ) = \log{2}+ O\left (\frac1n \right )$$

As $S_n$ decreases monotonically as $n \to \infty$, $S_n \ge \log{2} \gt 0.6$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  Thus, $S_n \gt \frac12$.